# What happens if one casts Blink while under Rary's Telepathic Bond?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

In D&D 5th Edition, the description of Rary's Telepathic Bond states that the link breaks if a character in it leaves the plane in which the other linked characters are. Since Blink actually pulls the character into the Ethereal Plane for a small duration, would that permanently break the bond for that character, or would it resume the instant he or she returns to the original Plane?

Moreover, what happens if the same character who cast Rary's Telepathic Bond casts Blink afterwards? Would it just sever that one character's connection, or end the spell altogether?

I can imagine three possible resolutions to this scenario (ordered by increasing level of rigidness on the DM's part):

1. The character is merely out of the bond for the duration of his or her stay in the Ethereal Plane (hearing static?), and the connection would resume as soon as he or she Blinks back.
2. The character is permanently out of the bond the first time he or she Blinks. The other characters stay linked regardless of whether that character cast the Bond initially (in my opinion, this interpretation is the closest to what the Rules as Written mean).
3. The character is permanently out of the Bond once he or she starts Blinking, and the Bond ends if it had been cast by that character.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Rary's Telepathic Bond* says nothing about the spell ending if the character leaves the plane, merely that the unlimited distance of the communication does not extend to another plane.**

> You forge a telepathic link among up to eight willing
>   creatures of your choice within range, psychically
>   linking each creature to all the others for the duration.
>   Creatures with Intelligence scores of 2 or less aren’t
>   affected by this spell.
>   Until the spell ends, the targets can communicate
>   telepathically through the bond whether or not they have
>   a common language. *The communication is possible
>   over any distance, though it can’t extend to other planes
>   of existence.* - *Player's Handbook* p.270

It says nothing at all about the spell ending. So the conflict in question you are asking about should not come up. The spell lasts for its duration (8 hours) or until the caster fails a concentration save (or chooses to end the spell/cast another concentration spell).

In case you are wondering though, *Blink* does put you completely in another plane for a few seconds (as everyone else takes their turn in a round).